# Database Firebase + RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have database on firebase.My app have RecyclerView. How to add database into RecyclerView???.  I try to do the same ListView but my app not run. Please help me. Thank you .
My code:

```
ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<SinhVienDTO>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<SinhVienDTO>>() {};
            ArrayList<SinhVienDTO> yourStringArray = snapshot.getValue(t);
            Toast.makeText(DanhSachSVActivity.this,yourStringArray.get(0).HoTenSV,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {
            Log.e("The read failed: " ,firebaseError.getMessage());
        }
    };
    mDatabase.child("SinhVien").addValueEventListener(postListener);
```

Comment: what you mean with no running ?

Comment: i want to get data from firebase to add RecyclerView.

Comment: the toast takes a CharSequence or an String resource id as its second argument i think that's why it's not showing

Comment: let me check, after i will answer for you